# Remap colors from table in ImageMagick

Tags: php, image-processing, colors, imagemagick

This is extremely trivial but I've been toiling trying to figure it out...

I have a table of rgb values and I would like ImageMagick to use that table to remap the coloring of my image.

I've implemented this fairly easily in PHP:

```
$table = array( 
  'red' => array(0,2,3,5,7...
  'green' => array(0,1,2,3,3...
  'blue' => array(50,50,5050...
);
```

I then loop through the width and height and get the color at each pixel

```
for( $h = 0; $h<$height; $h++) {
  for( $w = 0; $w<$width; $w++ ) {
    $rgb = ImageColorAt($img, $w, $h);
    $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
    // Then I remap it
    $r = $table['red'][$r];
```

How can I do this with ImageMagick on the command line? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create a look up table based on the array and then let Imagemagick use the look up table `-clut` to remap RGB values on the target image.

More info here: http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=24193&p=103407